# IIS rewrite doubling the domain

Tags: iis-7, url-rewrite-module

Can someone explain to me why this IIS redirect rule in the root directory of a IIS site for the following URL: `http://my.domain.com/hello.aspx` redirects to `http://my.domain.com/my.domain.com/hello.html`?

```
<rule name="redirect aspx" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*).aspx$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}.html" />
</rule>
```

If I put a `http://{R:1}.html` then it redirects to `http://hello.html/`. This is definitely making my head hurt...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules FRT can explain to you.

Comment: @LexLi, I don't have access to the server, nor the server config

Comment: You always have a Windows machine and can set up a similar local IIS instance for testing, right?

Comment: @LexLi It works fine on my Win 11 machine... But reliably does this on the Azure VM that I have been given. If I manually put the entire URL in the redirect, it works everywhere. `url="http://my.domain.com/{R:1}.html"` but that is nasty, and hardcodes the scheme.

Comment: It works well in my test. I tested it on windows server2019. Is there any more detailed information about reproducing this issue?

Comment: @BruceZhang, I'm afraid the server config is blackbox as far as I'm concerned. I guess it has some "security" on it for some reason. I suppose I will never know the precise reason...